# VSE: How to set as start frame where the cursor is in Blender 2.80

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Blender 2.80 seems such an awesome improvement that I have immediately switched to it. However, I can't find how to do something that was easy and useful in past versions. Namely, you would press S or E while hovering with the mouse over the timeline, and the current frame would become the start or end frame respectively. How can I do that now in Blender 2.80? The S key does not do that anymore. Is there maybe an icon, or menu option somewhere?

Specifically, **How to make the current frame in the vse the start frame?**

Comment: Shortcuts Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Timeline, Playback menu, <kbd>Set Start frame</kbd> and <kbd>Set End frame</kbd> buttons. If you Right-click them and assign them a shortcut, the shortcuts will also work in the VSE.

[image: Playback menu → Set Start Frame]